# JQUERY datatable from API request

Tags: jquery, json, api

I am very new to coding. I am attemting to use jquery to ready a JSON file from an API.

I would like to create a table containing columns for dividend amount, high and low prices for every month in each row.

Here is the JSON I am working with.
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY_ADJUSTED&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo

How do I go about doing this? I have tried quite a few ways, but with no luck.

Below is my jquery code and all i get is a "Loading..." message in the table. This is the tutorial I am going by (https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#example").dataTable({
    ajax:
      "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY_ADJUSTED&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo",
    columns: [
      { "Monthly Adjusted Time Series": "2020-09-25.7. dividend amount" },
      { "Monthly Adjusted Time Series": "2020-09-25.2. high" },
      { "Monthly Adjusted Time Series": "2020-09-25.3. low" }
    ]
  });
});
```

Any assistance would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the data uses nested objects with dynamically generated dates as keys I would do this slightly differently by making the request first and mapping the objects into an array of data to pass to the plugin.

Then initialize the plugin once the request and mapping has been completed.

Following uses `Object.entries()` and `Array#reduce()` to process the objects into array

```js
getData('IBM').then(initTable)

function getData(symbol) {
  let url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY_ADJUSTED&symbol=' + symbol + '&apikey=demo';

  // return ajax promise
  return $.getJSON(url).then(function(results) {
    const dataObjects = results["Monthly Adjusted Time Series"]; 
    // convert objects to simple array       
    return Object.entries(dataObjects).reduce(function(a, [date, obj]) {
      let arr =[date].concat(Object.values(obj))
      a.push(arr)
      return a;
    }, []);
  })
}

function initTable(dataArray) {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataArray,
    columns: [
      {title:'Date'},
      {title: "Open"},
      {title: "High"},
      {title: "Low"},
      {title: "Close"},
      {title: "Adjusted Close"},
      {title: "Volume"},
      {title: "Div"}
    ]

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%"></table>
```

Comment: Thank you charlietfl. Its going to take me some time for me to understand it, but thank you for helping out and I am going to try it out now! :)